# How to write json output to a CSV file using jq in a bash script?

Tags: bash, csv, jq

I have a JSON response from a API call as below and would like to write this to CSV file through a shell script.

**JSON response:**

```json
{
  "maxResults": 50,
  "startAt": 0,
  "isLast": true,
  "values": [
    {
      "id": 1986,
      "startDate": "2020-01-27T20:15:30.094Z",
      "endDate": "2020-02-24T20:15:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 1987,
      "startDate": "2020-02-24T20:48:40.618Z",
      "endDate": "2020-03-15T20:48:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 1988,
      "startDate": "2020-03-16T17:46:16.846Z",
      "endDate": "2020-04-24T17:46:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 1989,
      "startDate": "2020-04-20T17:59:30.920Z",
      "endDate": "2020-06-10T17:59:00.000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

the CSV file should look something like below

```
1986,2020-01-27T20:15:30:094Z,2020-02-24T20:15:00:000Z
1987,2020-02-24T20:48:40.618Z,2020-03-15T20:48:00.000Z
1988,2020-03-16T17:46:16.846Z,2020-04-24T17:46:00.000Z
1989,2020-04-20T17:59:30.920Z,2020-06-10T17:59:00.000Z
```

I have tried using jq but unable to figure out the correct way to write to csv

```
curl -X GET \
    --header 'Authorization: Basic <token>'  \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json'\
     "$url" | jq -r '[.values[].id, .values[].startDate, .values[].endDate] | @csv ' >> dates.csv
```

Any inputs would be helpful.

Comment: Is `jq -r '.values[] | [.id, .startDate, .endDate] | @csv'` (or shorter just dumping "all" items with `jq -r '.values[] | [.[]] | @csv'`) what you need?

Comment: Below command helped, thanks!
**`jq -r '.values[] | [.id, .startDate, .endDate] | @csv'`**

Answer (score 0):

this may depend on the api endpoint, but you could just request for CSV when calling your API. `curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: text/csv" 'https://some.api.endpoint.com/api/request.csv'` so you get the CSV response instead of having to convert it yourself.